# Evaluating type identifiers (%d) in strings, in C

Tags: c, string, append

I am working on Mac OSX and using bash as my shell. I am working in C and I am trying to create a file that will renumber files. The important part of my code is as follows:

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<numberOfFiles; i++) {
    strcpy(fileName,""); //Set to Null
    char append[formatLength]; //String being appended
    sprintf(append,"%%0%dd", formatLength); //example output: %04d
    strcat(fileName,filePrefix); //Attached Prefix
    strcat(fileName,append); //Attaches appended part

   //Missing code: Part which equvaluates %04d as int i, such as 0023.
}
```

This gets me the correct string format I am looking for (say formatLength=4): filePrefix+%04d. However, now I need to evaluate the %04d in the string and evaluate it as `i`, so that the files look like: file0001, file0002, etc.

Would anyone have any ideas. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So you need to add leading zeroes?

Comment: Or you need to get the value 4 out of file0004?   atoi(*ptr+4);

Comment: So you want your end result to be something like this: when `i=4`, result is `filePrefix0004`; when `i=123`, result is `filePrefix0123`. Is that correct?

Comment: wlyles, I don't think so.  I think he wants a dynamic format for his strings, based on formatlength.  If there aren't many options, how about a switch?

Comment: My earlier comment was assuming `formatLength = 4`. If it was 5, would you want `filePrefix00004` and `filePrefix00123` in my examples?

Comment: wlyles, yes I think so.

Comment: About to type an answer, but first a small tangent...  Always, _always_ use `snprintf`, `strncpy`, and `strncat` instead of their non-n variants. When used properly, they help prevent buffer overruns that can cause (sometime hard to find) bugs and security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Yes sorry, I am trying to have it such that when formatLength=4 and i=4 I get: file0004, or when i=4233 I get file4233. I realize if i=12345 I will get file12345, but I do not have over 10,000 files else I would just say formatLength=5. This is all for organization purposes since file1000 is right next to file001 instead of next to file999.

Comment: You have declared `append[]` to be `formatLength` characters, but `formatLength` is not related to the length of the format specifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to say

```
char result[(sizeof filePrefix/sizeof (char)) + formatLength];
sprintf(result, fileName, i);
```

since `fileName` looks something like `"filePrefix%04d"`. Your desired filename will be then stored in `result`. I would not recommend re-storing it in `fileName`by saying `sprintf(fileName, fileName, i)` because `fileName` may be too small (for example, when `formatLength = 9`).

Note that you need `(sizeof filePrefix/sizeof (char))` to find the size of `filePrefix` (which is likely also `char*`), and then you add `formatLength` to see how many more chars you need after that

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1 so `sizeof(filePrefix) + formatLength` is sufficient.  A `char` need not be 8 bits, but `sizeof(char)` remains 1 in any compliant implementation.  A type-independent expression would be `(sizeof(filePrefix)/sizeof(*filePrefix)) + formatLength`

Answer (score 3):

Use the string you created with `snprintf()` as the format string for the next call to `snprintf()`.

```
int formatLength = /* some input */;
char filePrefix[FILEPREFIX_LEN]; // assigned by some input
const int FILENAME_LEN = strlen(filePrefix) + formatLength + 1; // +1 for terminating '\0'
char fileName[FILENAME_LEN];

int i;
for (i=0; i<numberOfFiles; i++) {
    char temp[TEMPLATE_LEN]; // where TEMPLATE_LEN >= FILEPREFIX_LEN + 3 + number of characters in the decimal representation of formatLength
    snprintf(temp, TEMPLATE_LEN, "%s%%0%dd", filePrefix, formatLength);
    // error check snprintf here, in case the destination buffer was not large enough
    snprintf(fileName, FILENAME_LEN, temp, i);
    // error check snprintf here, in case the destination buffer was not large enough

    // use fileName
}
```

So if your `filePrefix` = "file" then you'd get `fileName` = "file0001", "file0002", "file0003", and so on...

Although a lot of this work isn't actually dependant on `i` so you could move it outside the loop, like this:

```
int formatLength = /* some input */;
char filePrefix[FILEPREFIX_LEN]; // assigned by some input
const int FILENAME_LEN = strlen(filePrefix) + formatLength + 1; // +1 for terminating '\0'
char fileName[FILENAME_LEN];

char temp[TEMPLATE_LEN]; // where TEMPLATE_LEN >= FILEPREFIX_LEN + 3 + number of characters in the decimal representation of formatLength
snprintf(temp, TEMPLATE_LEN, "%s%%0%dd", filePrefix, formatLength);
// error check snprintf here, in case the destination buffer was not large enough

int i;
for (i=0; i<numberOfFiles; i++) {
    snprintf(fileName, FILENAME_LEN, temp, i);
    // error check snprintf here, in case the destination buffer was not large enough

    // use fileName
}
```

In these cases, your `temp` (short for "template", not "temporary") is going to be "prefix%04d" (e.g., for a prefixLength of 4 and filePrefix of "prefix"). You need to take care, then, that your `filePrefix` does not contain any characters that have special meaning to the `printf` family of functions. If you know a priori that it won't, then you're good to go.

However, if it's possible it will, then you need to do one of two things. You can process the `filePrefix` before you use it by escaping all the special characters. Or you can change your `snprintf()` calls to something like these:

```
snprintf(temp, TEMPLATE_LEN, "%%s%%0%dd", formatLength);
// other stuff...
snprintf(fileName, FILENAME_LEN, temp, filePrefix, formatLength);
```

Note the extra `%` at the beginning of the first `snprintf()`. This makes the template pattern "%s%04d" (e.g., for a prefixLength of 4), and then you add the filePrefix on the second call so that it's contents are not part of the pattern string in the second call.

Comment: This doesn't address the main point, namely that the format string is dynamic, based on formatLength, which could be 4,5,6, etc.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting snprintf, but as @Jim said, I would like the format length to be dynamic.

Comment: Okay, I didn't understand before... I will edit accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @NoviceC See my updated code. `snprintf()` doesn't prevent your format length from being dynamic if you do it right, as I have shown. Although there is a chance that `snprintf()` will fail if your format length is a number too large to fit in the `temp` format string, but using `sprintf()` instead simply means it will overrun the buffer instead of giving an error, which will results in bugs and possibly security vulnerabilities. Therefore, it is safer to use `snprintf()` and have it tell you when there is a problem than to use `sprintf()` and not know when there is a problem.

Comment: @NoviceC Also, you could conservatiely make `temp` big enough to hold any possible formatLength, and then `snprintf()` shouldn't run out of space. How big does `temp` need to be? Well, you need space for the prefix, so `strlen(filePrefix)`, and for the `%`, `0`, and `d`, so `+3`, and the terminating `\0`, so `+1` more... and finally, you need enough space to print all the digits of `formatLength` ...but how many is that, since you don't know a priori what its value will be?

Comment: @NoviceC Well, you know `formatLength`'s data type (e.g., `int`, `long`, `unsigned int`) so you know what the maximum value the variable could possibly hold is. Count how many digits that is (let's call this `n`) and use that as a conservative figure. So the total length you need to make `temp` to be conservative is `strlen(filePrefix) + n + 4`. (If you need to set this size statically, or don't want to waste time counting chars in `filePrefix`, you can conservatively replace `strlen(filePrefix)` with the size of the `filePrefix` buffer.)

Answer (score 1):

You can build a format string then use that as a format string for another formatter call.  Note they the prefix and number format specifier can be built into a single string - no need for strcat calls.

Given:

```
char format_specifier[256] ;
```

then the loop code in your example can be replaced with:

```
snprintf( format_specifier,
          sizeof( format_specifier),
          "%s%%0%dd",
          filePrefix, 
          formatLength ) ; // Create format string "<filePrefix>%0<formatLength>", 
                           // eg. "file%04d"

snprintf( fileName,         // Where the filename will be built
          sizeof(fileName), // The length of the filename buffer
          format_specifier, // The previously built format string
          i ) ;             // The file number.
```

I have assumed above that `fileName` is an array, if it is a pointer to an array, then sizeof(fileName) will be incorrect.  Of course if you choose to use `sprintf` rather than `snprintf` it is academic.

Comment: Like the use of `snprintf()`.  Note: `formatLength` is the _minimum_ space needed for the textual version of `i`, it may need more.

Comment: @chux: Doh!  I made exactly the same error I commented on in the original question! Changed to just "reasonably large".

Answer (score 0):

sprintf(fileNameString, fileName, i);   // I think you mean this, but use snprintf()

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there

```
// This line could be done before the loop
sprintf(append,"%%0%dd", formatLength); //example output: %04d

// Location to store number
char NumBuffer[20];
// Form textual version of number
sprintf(NumBuffer, append, i);
strcat(fileName,filePrefix); //Attached Prefix
strcat(fileName,NumBuffer); //Attaches appended part
```